# Use QSignalSpy with Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework

Tags: c++, unit-testing, microsoft-cpp-unit-test, qsignalspy

I want to test whether a Qt Class correctly emits a signal upon function call using `QSignalSpy`. I use MS Visual Studio and use the `Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework`. Executing unit tests generally works fine, but instantiating a `QSignalSpy` yields a quite generic `Failed to set up the execution context to run the test` error which prevents all unit tests from executing. Compilation works fine, though.

This is the (simplified) class I want to test:

```cpp
// simcam.h
#include <QtCore>

class SimCam {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    SimCam() {};
    ~SimCam();

public slots:
    void connect() {
        emit(s_connected());
    };

signals:
    void s_connected();
};
```

and the unit test:

```cpp
#include "CppUnitTest.h"

#include "simcam.h"

#include <QSignalSpy>

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace devices_cameras_simcam_UnitTests {
    TEST_CLASS(ConnectionTests) {
public:

    TEST_METHOD(connectTest) {
        auto simcam = SimCam();

        // Problematic line
        QSignalSpy spy(&simcam, &SimCam::s_connected);

        simcam.connect();
        spy.wait();

        Assert::AreEqual(1, (int)spy.count());
    }
    };
}
```

I am a bit lost, how to get it to work or debug it. I didn't find any hint how to use `QSignalSpy` in combination with Visual Studio.

Comment: Alter test runner `main` function so it will instantiate `QApplication` or `QCoreApplication` object or drop `spy.wait();`. Basically with invocation of `spy.wait();` you are [requesting run of event loop](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsignalspy.html#wait) this means `QApplication` is needed.

Comment: Offtopic: your test leaks memory.

Comment: I will try that, but the problem already occurs simply by `QSignalSpy spy(simcam, &SimCam::s_connected);`. Calling `spy.wait();` is not necessary to trigger the issue.

Comment: > Offtopic: your test leaks memory.
Indeed. I tested so many variations of the code already, that I ended up with one leaking memory. Fixed it to not give a bad example.

Comment: You are right, it has to do something with the event loop. The line `QTestEventLoop m_loop;` in `QSignalSpy` triggers this issue. Not calling this line, makes the test run. I yet have to figure out how to properly instantiate a `QApplication`, though.

Comment: I couldn't figure out yet how to instantiate a `QApplication` in my test file. Having `QApplication` in the test requires it to be `moc`ed, but `moc` does not recognize the class with `TEST_CLASS(ConnectionTests)` and gives `No relevant classes found. No output generated.` leading to a linker error `unresolved externals`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically with invocation of `spy.wait();` (also other functionalities of `QSignalSpy` as you found out by testing) you are [requesting run of event loop](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsignalspy.html#wait) this means `QApplication` is needed.

In other test frameworks this means to provide own `main` function and instantiate there `QApplication` or `QCoreApplication`.

Problem is that `CppUnitTestFramework` uses dynamic libraries as tests suites which are loaded by some fixed tool, so you do now have access to `main` function.

The only choice is use initialization of module (whole test dll).
I would try this (didn't test that, but should resolve issue):

```cpp
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <memory>

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

static std::unique_ptr<QCoreApplication> myTestApplicationInstance;

TEST_MODULE_INITIALIZE(ModuleInitialize)
{
    static int argc = 1;
    static char testName[64] = "testSuiteName";
    static char *argv[2] = { testName, nullptr };

    myTestApplicationInstance = std::make_unique<QCoreApplication>(argc, argv);
}

TEST_MODULE_CLEANUP(ModuleCleanup)
{
    myTestApplicationInstance.reset();
}
```

[Documentation of Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-cppunittestframework-api-reference?view=vs-2022#test_modules)

> ##### Test modules
>
> ```cpp
> TEST_MODULE_INITIALIZE(methodName)
> {
>     // module initialization code
> }
> ```
>
> Defines the method *methodName* that runs when a module is loaded. `TEST_MODULE_INITIALIZE` can only be defined once in a test module and must be declared at namespace scope.
>
> ```cpp
> TEST_MODULE_CLEANUP(methodName)
> ```
>
> Defines the method *methodName* that runs when a module is unloaded. `TEST_MODULE_CLEANUP` can only be defined once in a test module and must be declared at namespace scope.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Unfortunately, this does not fix the problem, I still see `Failed to set up the execution context`. Is suspect the event loop is not acutally running, and one needs to call `myTestApplicationInstance->exec()`. But doing so in `TEST_MODULE_INITIALIZE` just hangs the tests as expected, because `exec()` does not return.

Comment: Consider switch testing framework. Qt has some own solution `QTestLib`, but I would recommend use of `gtest` which is kind of industry standard. There are lots of plugins for VisualStudio to utilize gtest.

Comment: Yes, I thought about this as well. Let's see whether I get this test to work with `gtest`.

Comment: I switched to Google Test. It works well with Qt and Visual Studio.